# Camel sometimes partially lose data while file transportation

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl, spring-camel

I have following code:

```
//sftp
from(String.format("sftp://%s@%s:%d/%s?password=%s&delete=true",
        sftpConfiguration.getUsername(),
        sftpConfiguration.getHost(),
        sftpConfiguration.getPort(),
        sftpConfiguration.getSourcePath(),
        sftpConfiguration.getPassword()))
    .process(new Processor() {
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) {
            try {
                isCsv = CSV.equals(new 
                Tika().detect(exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class), fileName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                ....
                return;
            }
            final List<Map<String, Object>> parsedLines = misCsvParser.parse(exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class), fileName);
            ...
        }
    }).to("seda:parsed_csv");

    from("seda:parsed_csv")
        .to(String.format("sftp://%s@%s:%d/%s?password=%s",
                    sftpConfiguration.getUsername(),
                    sftpConfiguration.getHost(),
                    sftpConfiguration.getPort(),
                    sftpConfiguration.getDestPathRejected(),
                    sftpConfiguration.getPassword()));
```

Briefly this code take files from `sftpConfiguration.getSourcePath()`, analyze it and then send it to the `sftpConfiguration.getDestPathRejected()`
On my local mashine it works well always but on test environment our QA noticed interesting behaviour: Sometimes file lose some data. For example input file - 20 MB but after analyzing application put file with size less than 20MB. For example it can be 6 MB. Moreover if to repeat this operation for the same file size will change. It can became 8 MB and so on. Thus behaviour is not predictable.

I assume that something wrong with resource hanling but I don't have ideas what can be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have some application writing those CSVs directly to the SFTP, right? If so, try adding the option "readLock=changed" to the URL. Then the file will only be picked up once it hasn't been changed for at least a second.

Comment: @noMad, No, user puts files to sftp folder directly

Comment: @noMad17, Looks like problem is not on the producer side because I tried to add additional **from** statement -  **.from("seda:file_upload")** and on another tube side: **producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeaders("seda:file_upload", multipartFile.getBytes(), headers)** but result the same

Comment: @noMad, thanks it works